# Geometric filtration for Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

I'm reading the paper by Eilenberg-Moore (https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02564371.pdf) about the Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence.

In section 11, they introduce the notion of Geometric filtration. This satisfies the algebraic properties mentioned in previous sections. But is there any geometric/topological intuition of why do we define like this?